# Random password generator in VS - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a random password generator using Visual Studio IDE and Python 3.6, I have wrote some code and after pressing F5 I see just blank black command prompt of Python, my code is down below, do anyone can help me with this? [Screen shot of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEqUF.png)

```
import string
import random

def randompassword():
  chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
  size = random.randint(8, 16)
  return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size,16))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the issue is that you are not actually executing the function, so Python has nothing to do. Try calling the function, like so

```
import string
import random

def randompassword():
  chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
  size = random.randint(8, 12)
  return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size,16))

print(randompassword())
```